# Where does Firebase specify using ESLint?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

When running `firebase init functions` it asks

```
Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable bugs and enforce style?
```

Apparently this preference is set in some file somewhere. What is this file? How do I change it say that I don't want to use ESLint? No, running `firebase init functions` again and telling it that I didn't want to use ESLint didn't get the message across.

In my project root directory I see in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.11.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0"
  }
```

Is that the file? Also in my project root directory I looked at `firebase.json`, `.firebaserc`, and `.eslintrc.json`, these files doesn't say anything about ESLint. In my functions folder there's a `package.json` but it doesn't say anything about ESLint.

Answer (score 3):

This is put in the `package.json` as part of the `scripts` section.

From a quick test I did, the linting is defined in `functions/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  ...
```

If I look in the `firebase.json` in my project's root, I see:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

So there it is configured to lint and build before each deploy.

Comment: My `functions/package.json` file doesn't have the `"lint": "eslint ."` line. My `firebase.json` doesn't have the `run lint` line. This morning I thought that perhaps I'd installed firebase functions globally, which might be overriding the local version, so I tried `firebase init functions -g` but that didn't work. `firebase deploy` is calling ESLint v.4.5.0 from somewhere, I can't figure out form where.

Comment: I put the lines from your files into my files, it didn't help.

Comment: Be more specific about what you want. I first thought that you wouldn't want to use eslint, but now I guess you can't set it up, right?